# Mock Declare var flow; in angular 5 karma and Jasmine

Tags: angular5, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock a variable for my spec file which is used to test a Angular 5 component. the variable is declared above class {} using declared keyword eg "declar var flow;" Please help me to mock set a value to it.

I am getting error while running the test case as flow is undefined

Comment: Please post your attempted solution so far. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I was able to solve this later. Thanks

Comment: window['variablevalue'] = 'variableName';